# In Python, partial function application (currying) versus explicit function definition

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying, partial-application

In Python, is it considered better style to:

- explicitly define useful functions in terms of more general, possibly internal use, functions; or,
- use partial function application to explicitly describe function currying?

I will explain my question by way of a contrived example.

Suppose one writes a function, _sort_by_scoring, that takes two arguments: a scoring function and a list of items.  It returns a copy of the original list sorted by scores based on each item's position within the original list.  Two example scoring functions are also provided.

```
def _sort_by_score(scoring, items_list):
    unsorted_scored_list = [(scoring(len(items_list), item_position), item) for item_position, item in enumerate(items_list)]
    sorted_list = [item for score, item in sorted(unsorted_scored_list)]
    return sorted_list

def _identity_scoring(items_list_size, item_position):
    return item_position

def _reversed_scoring(items_list_size, item_position):
    return items_list_size - item_position
```

The function _sort_by_score is never called directly; instead, it is called by other single-argument functions that pass a scoring function and their lone argument (a list of items) to _sort_by_scoring and return the result.

```
# Explicit function definition style
def identity_ordering(items_list):
    return _sort_by_score(_identity_scoring, items_list)

def reversed_ordering(items_list):
    return _sort_by_score(_reversed_scoring, items_list)
```

Obviously, this intent is better expressed in terms of function currying.

```
# Curried function definition style
import functools
identity_ordering = functools.partial(_sort_by_score, _identity_scoring)
reversed_ordering = functools.partial(_sort_by_score, _reversed_scoring)
```

Usage (in either case):

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> identity_ordering(foo)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> reversed_ordering(foo)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Apparent advantages of the explicit function definition style:

1. useful functions may be defined before the more general functions are, without raising NameErrors;
2. helper functions (e.g., scoring functions) could be defined within the function definition body;
3. possibly easier to debug;
4. code looks nice by virtue of "explicit is better than implicit."

Apparent advantages of curried function definition style:

1. expresses intent of functional programming idiomatically;
2. code looks nice by virtue of succinctness.

For defining "useful" functions, which of the two styles is preferred?  Are there other styles that are more idiomatic/Pythonic/etc.?

Comment: one a side note, currying and partial-application are two different things. Currying implies transforming the function to work one argument at a time. So you when you apply the first argument you get a function than then you can apply the second argument. Partial application is just fixing some parameters to the function invocation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to have the curried functions as part of a public interface, use explicit function definitions.  This has the following additional advantages:

1. It is easier to assign a docstring to an explicit function definition.  For `partial()` functions, you would have to assign to the `__doc__` attribute, which is somewhat ugly.
2. Real function definitions are easier to skim when browsing the module source.

I would use `functools.partial()` in a similar way to lambda expressions, i.e. for locally needed throw-away functions.

In your particular example, I'd probably use neither, drop the leading underscores and call

```
sort_by_score(identity_scoring, foo)
```

which seems the most explicit to me.

Comment: And... I can discard my answer, because Sven beat me to it :)

Comment: @ncoghlan:  Didn't we discuss something very similar two days ago? :)

Answer (score 2):

As a slight tangent, it's generally desirable to let the `sorted` builtin do as much the decorate-sort-undecorate work as is practical. For example:

```
def _sort_by_score(scoring, items_list):
    num_items = len(items_list)
    def score(entry):
        return scoring(num_items, entry[0])
    return [item for position, item in sorted(enumerate(items_list), key=score)]
```

(Only posted as an answer because blocks of code don't work as comments. See Sven's response for an answer to the actual question asked)

**Edit by someone else**:  The Python sort function iterates through the list and generates the list of keys first.  The `key()` function is called only once for each list item, in the order of the input list.  Thus, you can also use the following implementation:

```
def _sort_by_score(scoring, items_list):
    num_items = len(items_list)
    index = itertools.count()
    def score(entry):
        return scoring(num_items, next(index))
    return sorted(items_list, key=score)
```

(Only posted as a revision because blocks of code don't work as comments.)

Comment: This is certainly more elegant.  However, I have a more general case in which _sort_by_score operates on a list of items_list (called piles_list), and the corresponding scoring function takes four arguments: piles_list_size, pile_position, items_list_size, item position.  It isn't obvious to me how to use sorted with key in this case.  Perhaps it is a question for another time. =)  Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @Sven: interesting trick, I never thought of that! Now I'm wondering if the language definition guarantees that behaviour...

Comment: The [documentation of sorted](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) at least states that the key function is called only once per item.  Since this has to be done before the actual sorting, I can't imagine how this could ever change, but of course there is no guarantee.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's one of those "technically an implementation detail, but no sane implementation will violate the assumption" deals.